# jQuery: Div not showing (easeOutBounce)

Tags: jquery

I have this script:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('#showme').animate({top: '-=100px'}, 500, 'easeOutBounce');
});
```

That is just not working. I have jquery and jquery.easing.min.js linked. I also tried linking the jQuery UI library up, but that didn't do anything. What am I missing?

Here's my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rhz8x/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `display: none` from the element you're trying to animate. It worked for me.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhz8x/1/).